# Is there a way to drop a table/view if you do not know which it is in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to drop a view, but *sometimes* it is a table. How do I drop it whatever the case?

Example:

The state of t2 is ambiguous {table, view} due to another system:

```
create table t1 as (select 1);
create table t2 as (select 1);
```

or

```
create table t1 as (select 1);
create view t2 as select * from t1;
```

All I need to do is drop t2, but it seems I am constrained to drop either a table or a view. I tried doing both sequentially, but `IF EXISTS` does not suppress the following errors when it hits the opposing case:

```
drop view if exists t2;
ERROR:  "t2" is not a view
HINT:  Use DROP TABLE to remove a table.
```

or

```
drop table if exists t2;
ERROR:  "t2" is not a table
HINT:  Use DROP VIEW to remove a view.
```

How do I drop t2, regardless of its type?

Comment: I am in this exact same boat! I was about to make a question, there are no unique problems these days thankfully! sometimes it a view, sometimes it a table. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need dynamic SQL for that:

```
do
$$
declare 
  l_type text;
begin
  select case relkind
            when 'r' then 'table'
            when 'p' then 'table'
            when 'v' then 'view'
            when 'm' then 'materialized view'
            when 'f' then 'foreign table'
         end as object_type
     into l_type
  from pg_class
  where oid = 't2'::regclass;
  execute format ('drop %s if exists t2 cascade', l_type);
end;
$$
```